# PasteSpecial (Format and Value)

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have an excel program/button that creates a table.  The inputs are in a single row/multiple columns on sheet 1. The outputs are the same but on a sheet 2.  The headings on both sheets of the columns are the same.  On the input sheet, one of the column headings has a drop down menu and others have formulas.  When I click a button, the row is copied/pasted to the output sheet. I can repeat the process by selecting different items from the drop down box and pushing the button to run the program to populate the table on sheet 2.  The problem is the I only want to copy and paste values.  Changing the drop down box on sheet 1 changes all of the information on to the same item on sheet 2.

The code is as follow:

```
Sub AddHardware()
    Range("b5:m6").Copy Sheets("MTO").Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)                
End Sub
```

How do I only paste the values and the formatting (no formulas or drop downs)?

Comment: Since you are dealing with more than one sheet, you may want to explicitly use each workbook, like you did with Sheets("MTO").range, but not with rows.count (this is on the activesheet.)  Also, is your "dropdown" menu a data validation, filter, combobox, .........

Comment: It's a data validation list.

Comment: Can't you simply assign between the .Value members of the two cells, or iterate over them if it is a range? You could also use Copy then PasteSpecial if it is a range, but that uses the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do that. You can do values, then format. I used two variables (perhaps overkill, yes), but it will show you how you could use ranges to set the copy/destination range which would help in the long run.

```
Sub copy_val_format()
    Dim copyRng As Range
    Dim destRng As Range
    Set copyRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:M6")
    Set destRng = Sheets("MTO").Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    copyRng.Copy
    destRng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    copyRng.Copy
    destRng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

or the simpler version:

```
Sub simpler()
    Dim lastCell as Range
    Set lastCell = Sheets("MTO").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:M6").Copy
    lastCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:M6").Copy
    lastCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, BruceWayne.  This works. I had some merged cells but I fixed that.  It does the copy and paste job but when it copies the border it places them a row below the values in the cells. The cell values are spot on aside from the fact that there are way more sig figs than I need.  This using the simplier version.

Comment: @Mark - D'oh, see my edit.  It was adding the formatting to a row below, because when you added data to the `MTO` sheet, it re-ran the `...End(xlUp)` on *that* data, so had an extra row.  It should work now.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Works perfectly!

Comment: @Mark glad it worked! You can mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `PasteSpecial` with the `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` option.

```
Range("B5:M6").Copy
Sheets("MTO").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
                Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

After a copy operation, I sometimes want to clear the clipboard so the copied range isn't accidentially pasted again.  I use this procedure:

```
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Public Sub ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Sub
```

You can add this at the top of a regular code module and then call it from any of your procedures with this line of code:

```
ClearClipboard
```