# vba macro to copy data from one sheet and save it a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

The following code is supposed to copy all my data from one of the sheets in the current workbook, paste that into a new workbook and then save that workbook in the same directory as the current workbook.

```
Sub copy_to_new_workbook()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary_data").Copy


' Create new Workbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

' Name it and paste data
NewBook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:="export.xlsx"


End Sub
```

However what happens, is it creates a new excel file called `"export.xlsx"` and all that is copied is my vba code? Additionally a new workbook opens up called like `book2` or `book3`, this workbook has my required data but it is not saved?

Additionally I would like to save the new workbook with a title such as: `export_DD_MM_YYYY` with todays date in the name field.

Thanks.

Comment: are the closing double quotes missing in your real code as well?

Comment: no they're not, edited my post now

Comment: What happens when you start the macro recorder and copy the sheet to a new workbook, then stop the macro recorder? That should give you the starting point for correct code.

Comment: Your code copies a sheet as an object, but the paste command is what you would use to past a copied range, not a sheet object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary_data").Copy
```

creates a copy of the sheet (not the contents) - if you don't specify where that copy should be located then it will be created in a new workbook.

At that point you can just call

```
Set NewBook = Activeworkbook
```

and save it.

If you only want to copy the sheet contents then you could use:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary_data").Cells.Copy
```

or

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary_data").UsedRange.Copy
```

Comment: I receive compile error "method or data member not found" this is on the Set NewBook = Workbooks.ActiveWorkbook line

Comment: Thanks, can I easily modify this so that it pastes as values, but keeps source formatting, such as keep dates as dates and revenue and costs as $'s ?

Comment: Yes, using `PasteSpecial`

Comment: Okay I was thinking that, but there is no pasting in the code right, just copying?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410764/pastespecial-format-and-value